# Phonegap application with plugin on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to make a Phonegap app for android and I have a problem that I can't figure out...
I used this tutorial for my first plugin http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/ (I didn't copy past the code) and I created a plugin that works.

The problem came up when I moved the "web application" from the android device to my computer, ran in on apache and loaded the url on the device... The page comes up just fine and I get the "Device ready" message, but my plugin does not work...

Do I have to do anything differently if I want to run an external url?

Comment: What is your plugin about? What would you expect to see? It will most likely not run as cordova or phonegap is about accessing native functions of mobile devices which your desktop computer will not have.

Comment: I'm just trying to get any response really... I'm just hosting the page on my computer and accessing it with my android device... I just changed the super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());  to  super.loadUrl(myComputersIP);

Comment: Did you add your IP address to the whitelist? Are you seeing anything in the logcat? Are you running a server to actually host the files on the Internet? Can you type in your IP address and access those files just fine?

Comment: Turns out you can't really use plugins if you're accessing an external site so I'll have to set the site up internally or find some other way to send some data to the webapp.... Tnx for the help anyway :)